# Realm.io and Facebook Android SDK problems

Tags: android, facebook, realm

I have an Android app that uses Realm as a database. Right now when I add a Facebook SDK, my app does not work. The error is with this line:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
```

Anyone with the same problem or some solutions?

Regards,

Noel

Comment: Can you please share the exact error log?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.internal.RealmCore
                                                                at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:388)

Comment: Are you enabling Multidex? this could be similar to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2837 can you share your Gradle/ProGuard configuration

Comment: I solve the problem, is with the miltidex compilation. I recompile de app and it is working right now.